# Best way to describe this: "There is only one of this bone in a human body."

Tags: sentence-construction

For example there is only one nasal bone in a human body. While teaching bones in a human body to student before the skeleton model which sentence should I say by showing nasal bone? Or can I use both of them? Especially I wonder if the first one is correct or not.

> 1. There is only one of this bone in a human body.

> 2. There is only one example of this bone in a human body.

Comment: this bone is unique?

Comment: Thanks . What about my sentences?

Comment: your second sentence works for me, maybe "This is only one bone of this kind in a human body"? You could also start with "The nasal bone(s) is/are"

Comment: ...Except there are two nasal bones, each is small oblong and they meet in a junction in the middle of the face.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_bone#:~:text=The%20nasal%20bones%20are%20two,two%20surfaces%20and%20four%20borders.

Comment: Either of them works as does @AndrewTobilko suggestion.